# difference between Associative Arrays and Objects in JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, associative-array

Looked on the web and cannot rule out best describe of diff between associative arrays and objects in js. And the main diff in their usings

Comment: Objects are associative arrays; the only other array in JS is zero-indexed and doesn't have other keys.

Comment: I must disagree... object != array, associative or not, and since everything in JS is an object... arrrrgh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that an associative array doesn't exist in JS and objects do